# HTML5 DRM video won't play on Ubuntu 15.10 with latest Google-Chrome

Tags: video, google-chrome, ffmpeg, drm

I have three 15.10 systems with Google Chrome installed.  Two play purchased Amazon movies just great.  One gives me a "Digital Rights Error" tells me to enable Widevine and refer to error 7235.  I think this is a problem with Chrome DRM, not with Amazon because the test video here won't play on the problem system either (it plays great on the working systems):
http://www.dash-player.com/demo/drm-test-area/

I did a quick look through my packages and I've got chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra, gstreamer-ugly, and similar packages all installed.  I've tried:

- Installing, then uninstalling mjblenner's zombie hal package
- Signed in and signed out of my Google account in Chrome
- Forcing the user to sign in to the Ubuntu desktop, or allowing it to log in without signing in
- Logging out of my Google account in Chrome, deleting all data from the Settings windows, uninstalling chrome, deleting ~/.config/google-chrome, then re-installing chrome.

The only other difference between the working systems and the non-working systems is that the Chrome version number says

`Version 48.0.2564.109`

on the working systems and

`Version 48.0.2564.109`**`unknown`**

on the system that doesn't play DRM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also asked here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/chrome/QUPNuAndwAI/X9--o_OuBQAJ

JPApen suggested I install google-chrome-beta instead of google-chrome-stable and that fixed it - yay!  They also said that google-chrome-stable would have this fixed in a couple weeks (today is 2016-02-14)

## Details

I opened "Software & Updates" from the dash, picked the "Other Software" tab, clicked the **Add** button, and where it says "**apt line**" I put:

```
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ beta main
```

That's the same as the *stable* apt line except for the word *beta*.

Then from a command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-beta
```

I actually used `purge` instead of `remove` because this is a relatively new installation and I didn't care about keeping my settings.  Note that purge now removes your repository as well.

I did NOT need

- hal
- to be signed into chrome
- flashplugin-installer or any kind of flash (I think)